# What are the benefits of postgresql functions over sending queries from the app layer?

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures, web-applications

I am working on a webapp written in python with some complex database queries. Would I be gaining anything by writing these queries as postgresql functions and simply querying this functions from the application it is it preferable to write all queries at the application level?

I am looking to see answers that explain the pros and cons of each method as they relate to readability, speed of development, and speed of performance.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to consider is the affect on new version releases. I have a non-web python app and I separate the Postgresql sql and functions from the Python app. It allows the customer to more easily organise updates relating to Postgresql without having to alter the Python code. I'm not saying it is always best to do this, it's just something to consider